# How add icon from Angular Material in background-image?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, icons

How add an arrow_forward icon from Angular Material in bacground-image (in :after)? This icon does not need to download. I don't know how to get it in css.

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #adb8c1;

  &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -25px;
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<md-list class="list">
  <div class="item"></div>
</md-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help

```
&:after {
font-family: "Material Icons"; 
content: "\E876";
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
right: -25px;
display: block;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
background: blue;
```

}

Comment: The declaration content: "\E3E7"; sets the codepoint of the icon to be used. For example, you can use the code \E312 as value of the content property to get a keyboard icon. Available material design icons codepoints:https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/codepoints